# I send 'name' in Postman and ValidatorExpress returns that 'name' has not been provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

When in Postman I use the 'POST' method and url: `http: // localhost: 7777 / register`, I also choose`Body` and `row` and paste the object`{name: 'Martin}`. Why in `[" You must supply a name! "," That Email is not valid! "," Password Cannot be Blank! "," Confirmed Password cannot be
blank "," Oops! Your passwords do not match "]` returns me `You must supply a name!"`Since I gave my name in body? In addition, it gets the status: `500Internal Server Error`.

**Routes: index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

router.get('/register', userController.registerForm);

router.post('/register',
  userController.validateRegister,
  userController.register
);

module.exports = router;
```

**Models: User.js**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const validator = require('validator');
    const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
    const mongodbErrorHandler = require('mongoose-mongodb-errors');


    const userSchema = new Schema ({
        name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: 'Please supply a name'
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true,
            trim: true,
            validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid Email address'],
            required: 'Please supply an email address'
        }
    })

    userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'email'});
    userSchema.plugin(mongodbErrorHandler);

    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**controllers: userController.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const {promisify} = require("es6-promisify");

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
    res.json('res');
  };

  exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
    req.sanitizeBody('name');
    req.checkBody('name', 'You must supply a name!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'That Email is not valid!').isEmail();
    req.sanitizeBody('email').normalizeEmail({
      remove_dots: false,
      remove_extension: false,
      gmail_remove_subaddress: false
    });
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password Cannot be Blank!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Confirmed Password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Oops! Your passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
      res.send('error', errors.map(err => err.msg));
      return; // stop the fn from running
    }
    next(); // there were no errors!
  };

  exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = new User({ email: req.body.email, name: req.body.name });
    const register = promisify(User.register, User);
    await register(user, req.body.password);
    next(); // pass to authController.login
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have the proper body parser installed. For example, if you want to handle JSON, add this to your express app setup:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// ...

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Without a body parser, `req.body` will not be populated as you expect.

You'll also want to make sure that the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json` so that your server knows that the body contains JSON.

Comment: It helped me: Content-Type header is set to application/json